# Interpolation in R when there are 3 columns

Tags: r

I need to find the interpolated value for consumption from the speed and weather.

I have tried approx function but it is only for 2 variables, wont accept three or more.

```
Speed weather fuel
10     2       30
12     3       35
14     8       38
15     9       65
```

need to find fuel for speed_new = 13 and weather = 7.

```
approx(x=Speed,y=Fuel,z=Weather,xout= speed_new,rule = 2)$y #need to also mention the weather
```

Comment: Have a look at `lm` then `predict`

Comment: You could also check out the `broom` package for working with statistical models.